# jQuery change the value of an list that already appended

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace a list item in my website using jQuery. The code works, but it only works once. I change the `content-ul` list into `content-appetizer` but then I can't change the list into `content-menu`. The list will stay the moment I click on the `content-appetizer`.

HTML:

```
<center>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu">This week <br> <b style="color: orange; font-size: 18px;">Menu</b></li>
        <li><h2 style="font-size: 25px;" > Home Cooking </h2></li>
        <li class="appetizer">This week <br> <b style="color: orange; font-size: 18px;">Appetizer</b></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<center>    
<div class="content">
    <ul class="content-ul">
        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/nasigoreng.jpg" >
            <h3>Nasi Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried rice indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/ikanbakar.jpg">
            <h3>Ikan Bakar</h3>
            <p>Fried fish with red Javanese traditional sauce.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/miegoreng.jpg">
            <h3>Mie Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried noodle indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Sapi</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
</center>

<center>    
<div class="content-menu">
    <ul class="content-ul">
        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/nasigoreng.jpg" >
            <h3>fried rice</h3>
            <p>Fried rice indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/ikanbakar.jpg">
            <h3>Ikan Bakar</h3>
            <p>Fried fish with red Javanese traditional sauce.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/miegoreng.jpg">
            <h3>Mie Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried noodle indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Sapi</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
</center>

<center>    
<div class="content-appetizer">
    <ul class="content-ul">
        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/nasigoreng.jpg" >
            <h3>fried tofu</h3>
            <p>Fried rice indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/ikanbakar.jpg">
            <h3>hello</h3>
            <p>Fried fish with red Javanese traditional sauce.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/miegoreng.jpg">
            <h3>Mie Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried noodle indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Sapi</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Nasi Ramez</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Bubur Ayam</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Ayam</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Ayam</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</center>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('.appetizer').click(function(){
        var list_new = $('.content-appetizer').html();
        $('.content-ul').fadeOut(1000).empty(100).append(list_new).fadeIn(1000);
    });

        $('.menu').click(function(){
        var list_new1 = $('.content-menu').html();
        $('.content-ul').fadeOut(1000).empty(100).append(list_new1).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you give us a more clear idea of what you end-goal is here? It seems like each click of the buttons will just continuously embed lists within lists. If you clearly outline what you're trying to attain, we can probably provide you with a more concise solution.

Comment: The problem is that you empty the content-ul when clicking. So when you click for the second time you try to access an empty element.

Comment: My approach: Set all the divs to `display: none;`, then `.fadeToggle()` whatever list you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) & classes on specific `ul` you can make it work like this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.appetizer').click(function(){
        var list_new = $('.content-appetizer').html();
        $("ul.dynamic").closest('div').hide();
        $('.content-appetizer').show('slow');
    });
    $('.menu').click(function(){
      var list_new1 = $('.content-menu').html();
      $('ul.dynamic').closest('div').hide();
      $('.content-menu').show('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class='main'>
        <li class="menu">This week <br> <b style="color: orange; font-size: 18px;">Menu</b></li>
        <li><h2 style="font-size: 25px;" > Home Cooking </h2></li>
        <li class="appetizer">This week <br> <b style="color: orange; font-size: 18px;">Appetizer</b></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<center>    
<div class="content">
    <ul class="dynamic content-ul">
        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/nasigoreng.jpg" >
            <h3>Nasi Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried rice indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/ikanbakar.jpg">
            <h3>Ikan Bakar</h3>
            <p>Fried fish with red Javanese traditional sauce.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/miegoreng.jpg">
            <h3>Mie Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried noodle indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Sapi</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
</center>

<center>    
<div class="content-menu">
    <ul class="dynamic content-ul">
        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/nasigoreng.jpg" >
            <h3>fried rice</h3>
            <p>Fried rice indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/ikanbakar.jpg">
            <h3>Ikan Bakar</h3>
            <p>Fried fish with red Javanese traditional sauce.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/miegoreng.jpg">
            <h3>Mie Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried noodle indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Sapi</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
</center>

<center>    
<div class="content-appetizer">
    <ul class="dynamic content-ul">
        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/nasigoreng.jpg" >
            <h3>fried tofu</h3>
            <p>Fried rice indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/ikanbakar.jpg">
            <h3>hello</h3>
            <p>Fried fish with red Javanese traditional sauce.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/miegoreng.jpg">
            <h3>Mie Goreng</h3>
            <p>Fried noodle indonesian style with either chicken,lamb and beef</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Sapi</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Nasi Ramez</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Bubur Ayam</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Ayam</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="content-li">
            <img src="image/sotoayam1.jpg">
            <h3>Soto Ayam</h3>
            <p>Traditional Javanese soup with rice and beef.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</center>
```

Hope this helps!